# How to display dialog box from from c2dmreceiver in android

Tags: android

At present i am working on c2dm in android.i am sending messages from server but messages are displaying on Log cat.But i want to display dialog when message occur how can i do this.

Please help me.

Comment: Does the Log-output occur because you handled it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you cannot display dialog boxes from broadcast receivers. At most, you can start up an activity, perhaps one themed to look like a dialog.

Second, popping up an activity like this is generally frowned upon. You have no idea what the user is doing at the time, and they may not appreciate your activity taking over the foreground. Only a select handful of applications (VOIP clients, alarm clocks, etc.) should do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the notifications framework to notify the user by dropping an icon in the notification bar. This is less obtrusive, but gives the user some visual cue that something has happened.